# Merge two filtered data horizontally in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

in my Spreadsheet I have two filter functions:

```
=FILTER(T3:Z;S3:S=FALSE)
=FILTER(AC:AI;AC3:AC<>"")
```

The first filter returns 10 rows and 7 columns
The second filter returns 8 rows and 7 columns

I want all the rows in one list of 18 rows and 7 columns. I don't know if it's simple but I cant get the desired result.

Here is an example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10Aa8IkK1tKjEEizBCuqZTe3_820z7IQlt8s4u771uu0/edit?usp=sharing

As I wrote in the Spreadsheet, I want this: if row are not checked in first table, bring row data of first table. If row are checked in first table, bring row data of second table.
In my real document, when a row is checked in the first table, the data is stacked automatically in the second table.

I don't know if it's better with query, filter..., but I'm trying to avoid using VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added formula to your sheet:

```
=sort({filter(B2:H19;not(A2:A19));J2:P9};7;0)
```

[image]

Comment: Your formula works well, but the issue appears when trying to work with column ranges. I posted an approach to what i need:
=sort({filter(B2:H;not(A2:A));filter(J2:P;not(isblank(J2:J)))};7;0)
so, the second table has to be also a filter of rows (when J column is not empty for example), so the formula should work automatically with any number of rows checked.

Comment: no problem it's done. the issue was that check column count empty rows as FALSE even if there is no checkbox, so I had to add a second condition in the filter to filter if first column has a value and checkbox is not checked. thank you very much